# AWS architecture when multi-regions

Tags: architecture, amazon-web-services, scalability

I've been introduced recently to AWS and I really loved it. However, I'm asking myself some questions (that may be stupid) about architecturing for multi-regions.

Let's say an application is used by Europeans and Asians. My first idea was to add EC2 instances in Europe, as well as a S3 bucket to hold static data and a SQS queue and ElastiCache in Europe. It's going to be blazingly fast for European people, but slower for asians.

To solve this, I'd add CloudFront for static data, so that images are served quickly for Asians too. However, requests to server (Ajax requests...) still going to have some latencies, so the solution would be to add an EC2 instance in Singapore/Tokyo region too.

However, new problem arise: if a request is dispatched to Tokyo EC2 instance, then if it needs to receive a message from SQS that is stored in Europe or access ElastiCache data => latency again + costs for inter-regions transfer. So we need to add a SQS and ElastiCache in Asia too ?

Maybe I miss something, and cross-regions AWS requests are super-fast, but from what I've understood, if we want fast experience for multi-regions, we basically need to duplicate all services too every regions (excepting S3 maybe, as we can use CloudFront for that, and I suppose we can live with the latency if a SQS job in Asia need to access a S3 resource in Europe).

Anyway, did I understand this correctly ? Do you have any resources about how to architecture applications that target multi-regions ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

These aren't stupid questions at all!  This part is absolutely correct:

```
Maybe I miss something, and cross-regions AWS requests are super-fast, but from
what I've understood, if we want fast experience for multi-regions, we basically
need to duplicate all services too every regions
```

Cross-region requests will be limited by the speed of light and the network topology between regions.  I would expect requests from Asia to reach the European application in about 1/4 second round trip.  Most requests would be faster, but you can't guarantee all of them will be faster, so you have to design accordingly.  If that isn't fast enough, then yes, you'll need to deploy to a closer region and route users to the appropriate region.  The number of times that round trip is required is up to your application's architecture.  If you have many requests to Elasticache or SQS, those 1/4 seconds will add up very quickly.  If you can batch the requests, it might be tolerable.

To route users to the appropriate region, you'll want to look at [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/), which is another part of the AWS family.  [This announcement](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/latency-based-multi-region-routing-now-available-for-aws.html) about Route 53 describes the latency-based routing between regions that you would need.  Once users are routed to the appropriate EC2 instances, each region you've deployed to should be isolated.  You would configure your European deployment with EC2, SQS, Elasticache, and any other AWS offerings all served from the European region (eu-west-1).  For your Asian deployment, you might host it all in the ap-southeast-1 region.  Once Route 53 connects an Asian user to an EC2 instance within ap-southeast-1, the requests to SQS, Elasticache, etc. would be within the same region and thus very fast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I have two SQS queues (one in Tokyo region and one in Ireland), does this mean that I have to serve two different applications in EC2 to connect to the right SQS queue ? Or is Route 53 smart enough to also dispatch to the right SQS queue based on location ?

Comment: Producing to SQS doesn't go through Route 53, so you'll have to produce to the correct queue yourself from within your application.  Route 53 will just direct requests to the nearest endpoint based on latency (assuming that's how you configure it).  Your application can consume from both queues, just be aware that whichever queue is in the remote region will take longer.

Answer (score 1):

The utilities model that Amazon Web Services introduced is helping you to deploy the same service in multiple regions. The same CLI commands/web console/CloudFormation scripts are working in all the regions in the same way. Therefore to launch a similar service in Singapore and in Europe should not be complicated for you. More than that, you can also manage all of them from the same location - the power of the cloud.

It will also not going to be more expensive as you are paying for what you use, and if you distribute the load between the regions, you will have more or less the same cost. For example, if you need 10 servers to serve your users, you can have 5 servers in Europe and 5 servers in Singapore. More than than; you can have different number of servers in different regions based on the hour of load using [auto-scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/). for example, 8 server in Europe when Europe is awake and only 2 in Singapore when it is night there, and vice versa.

With the combination of the above multi-region services (EC2, S3, ElasticCache, RDS...) with Amazon CloudFront (CDN) and Route 53 (DNS) you can create a very scalable and affordable service, with excellent latency globally (Europe, Asia, North and South America...).

Comment: Thanks, auto-scaling based on awaken region is really interesting. I will investigate this more closely.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you may be able to achieve your objectives using a single AWS Region, and leveraging the AWS Edge Network. If you are using an Application Load Balancer or an API Gateway as the entry point to your service, then you can make use Amazon CloudFront. User requests will be routed to the closest AWS Edge location ([there are over 400 of these](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/)), and either served from cache right there, or the request will be forwarded to the Region hosting your service over the AWS backbone. The AWS backbone will provide the quickest, most reliable connection from your user to the service running in the AWS Region. Also for non-https traffic, you can consider using AWS Global Accelerator, which similarly onboards requests at the closes edge location to the user and then uses the AWS backbone network.

You still have to incur "speed of light" for non-cached content, but this may be a workable solution.